# Title value is not being pulled in for hyperlink inserted in 'Rich Text' fields

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, rtf, sites-9.5

When I try to insert a hyperlink using the 'Hyperlink' button for any Rick text field, I am able to enter a value for 'title'. The title is also showing up in the source tab as <a title="sampletitle>. But the title value is not showing up in the web app. It is not being pulled into the application with the rich text html, and showing up in the application HTML as

The expected markup (with the title attribute) is published to the broker database and I can view it there.But is not being rendered in the view. Any as to why that could be happening

Also, what would be the ideal datatype we should be using in our view to render the Rich text field

Comment: Which data type are you using for the property in your View Model?  And which code do you use in your View to render it?